# Read Input and Display Output in Star

Tags: arrays, c, loops

I want to create a program that can read scores from user and display the scores output in the form of stars. But it seems that my code keep getting an infinity loop. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my looping.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, k, j;
    int score[5];
    
    for(i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("\nplease enter the score for %d match : ", i);
        scanf("%d", &score[i]);
    }

    printf("\nstatistics collection points for 5 matches\n\n");
    
    for (k = 1; k < 6; k++) {
        printf("%d. ", k);

        for (j = 1; j <= score[k]; j++) {
            printf("*");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Array indices are 0 based in C. So for an array with 5 elements the indices are from 0-4 inclusive. You are using indices 1-5 which results in buffer overflow. Below is the corrected program with the `for` loops fixed up to use the right indices:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_SCORES 5

int main()
{
    
    int i, k, j;
    int score[NUM_SCORES];
    
    for(i = 0; i < NUM_SCORES ; i++)
    {
        printf("\nplease enter the score for %d match : ", i);
        scanf("%d", &score[i]);
    }
    printf("\nstatistics collection points for 5 matches\n\n");
    
    for (k = 0; k < NUM_SCORES ; k++){
        printf("%d. ", k);
        for(j = 1; j <= score[k]; j++){
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You should also add a check to ensure `scanf` is able to successfully read each input.